# JSPM doesn't resolve css @import

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, bundle, jspm

Trying to build very basic project with **JSPM** and **jquery-ui**, but error occurs due to this line at main.js.

```
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css!'
```

> jspm_packages\github\components\jqueryui@1.12.1\themes\base\base.css
>   not found! TODO: ensure these imports are normalized correctly.
>   jspm_packages\github\components\jqueryui@1.12.1\themes\base\theme.css
>   not found! TODO: ensure these imports are normalized correctly.

*all.css* contains *@import* and JSPM can't resolve it for some reason.

Steps to reproduce:

```
npm init -y &
npm install jspm -D &
jspm init -y &
jspm install jquery-ui &
jspm install css &
echo import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css!' > main.js &
jspm bundle main.js
```

Question is how to import css from third-party modules that contains @import?

Tried to `jspm install npm:postcss-import` but error occured

> Error processing package config for npm:pkg-resolve.

Authors says "jspm - Frictionless Browser Package Management", but i feel to much frictions even at first steps :) or maybe i am doing something totally wrong?